# Wrangle cell array of various-sized cell arrays into cell array of cell arrays of size {1xN}

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I'm trying to wrangle combnk to generate all the combinations of strings in a cell. E.g.:

```
someStrings = {'a','b','dog','goat'};
results = arrayfun(@(k) combnk(someStrings,k),1:length(someStrings),'UniformOutput',0);
```

This gives me a `4*1` cell array of cell arrays with the following dimensions:

```
{4x1 cell}    {6x2 cell}    {4x3 cell}    {1x4 cell}
```

What I want is a `15*1` cell array of cell arrays, each of size `{1xN}`; i.e. 4 cell arrays of size `{1,1}`, 6 of size `{1,2}`, etc. How can I do this efficiently?

EDIT: Okay, now I'm here:

```
results = transpose(arrayfun(@(k) num2cell(combnk(someStrings,k),2),1:length(someStrings),'UniformOutput',0));
finalResults = vertcat(results{:});
```

Is it possible to turn that into one line? How do you index into a cell array like "{:}", but in the line the cell array was created?

Comment: If any of the answers below satisfied your requirements, please accept that answer by clicking the check-mark on the left hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it as follows:

```
intermResults=cellfun(@(x) num2cell(x,2),results,'uni',0);
finalResults=vertcat(intermResults{:});
```

Explaination: If you look at your `results` variable, you have those 15 cells. You just need to extract out each row and make it a cell. This is what `num2cell(x,2)` does. By wrapping it into `cellfun`, I apply it to each cell in the cell array `results`. Now you have a `1x4` cell in which each row of results has been converted into a separate cell. You just need to concatenate it to produce the final answer. That's what `vertcat(intermResults{:})` does.

Comment: This is very close to doing what I want. However, if I'm trying to do this in one line, it doesn't quite work. I've edited my post with an update.

Comment: My mistake. I now separated it in two lines. However, look at @LuisMendo's solution. I prefer that. I gave a solution which keeps yours intact and just builds on it but I think LuisMendo's soluion will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
m = dec2bin(1:2^numel(someStrings)-1)-'0'; %// each row contains indices of a combination
[~, s] = sort(sum(m,2)); %// compute sum of each row, sort and get sorting indices
m = m(s,:); %// sort rows according to sum
[jj, ii] = find(m.'); %'// find column indices (jj), ordered by row (ii)
result = accumarray(ii, jj, [], @(x){someStrings(x)}); %// group col indices of each row
```

This gives, for your example `someStrings`,

```
>> result
result = 
    {1x1 cell}
    {1x1 cell}
    {1x1 cell}
    {1x1 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x4 cell}
```

where

```
>> result{1}
ans = 
    'goat'
>> result{2}
ans = 
    'dog'
>> result{3}
ans = 
    'b'
>> result{4}
ans = 
    'a'
>> result{5}
ans = 
    'dog'    'goat'
>> result{6}
ans = 
    'b'    'goat'
[...]
>> result{15}
ans = 
    'a'    'b'    'dog'    'goat'
```